# Missing archivelogs when restoring duplicate

Tags: oracle, rman

We restore backups to our test systems from production via a point in time RMAN Duplicate with an online full backup and hourly archivelog.  Every blue moon something goes wrong (working to resolve that separately) and I end up not having an archive log.  It spends hours restoring the datafiles, gets to the archivelogs and then bombs.

How can I verify that RMAN has all the correct archivelogs and datafiles to restore before it starts pushing the data around significantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RESTORE ... PREVIEW`. I intentionally deleted some archivelogs, so I do not have a backup of them.

Now I want to check if I can restore the database to a specified time:

```
run
{
  set until time "to_date('2018-11-12 19:58:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
  restore database preview;
}
```

Output:

```
executing command: SET until clause

Starting restore at 12-NOV-18
using channel ORA_DISK_1


List of Backup Sets
===================


BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
4       Full    1.11G      DISK        00:00:03     11-NOV-18
        BP Key: 4   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20181111T221533
        Piece Name: /oracle_backup/DOMINO_O77/04thvv85_1_1
  List of Datafiles in backup set 4
  File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Abs Fuz SCN Sparse Name
  ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----------- ------ ----
  1       Full 2397081    11-NOV-18              NO    +DATA/DOMINO_O77/DATAFILE/system.257.991918055
  3       Full 2397081    11-NOV-18              NO    +DATA/DOMINO_O77/DATAFILE/sysaux.258.991918107
  4       Full 2397081    11-NOV-18              NO    +DATA/DOMINO_O77/DATAFILE/undotbs1.259.991918131
  7       Full 2397081    11-NOV-18              NO    +DATA/DOMINO_O77/DATAFILE/users.260.991918133

no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 63 and starting SCN of 2784642 found to restore
no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 64 and starting SCN of 2784723 found to restore
no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 68 and starting SCN of 2784830 found to restore

List of Backup Sets
===================


BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
7       151.71M    DISK        00:00:01     12-NOV-18
        BP Key: 7   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20181112T195537
        Piece Name: /oracle_backup/DOMINO_O77/09ti2bdp_1_1

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 7
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    43      2396293    11-NOV-18 2397794    11-NOV-18
  1    44      2397794    11-NOV-18 2398565    11-NOV-18
  1    45      2398565    11-NOV-18 2398568    11-NOV-18
  1    46      2398568    11-NOV-18 2398574    11-NOV-18
  1    47      2398574    11-NOV-18 2398581    11-NOV-18
  1    48      2398581    11-NOV-18 2398588    11-NOV-18
  1    49      2398588    11-NOV-18 2398606    11-NOV-18
  1    50      2398606    11-NOV-18 2398912    11-NOV-18
  1    51      2398912    11-NOV-18 2498959    11-NOV-18
  1    52      2498959    11-NOV-18 2498962    11-NOV-18
  1    53      2498962    11-NOV-18 2499076    11-NOV-18
  1    54      2499076    11-NOV-18 2499560    11-NOV-18
  1    55      2499560    11-NOV-18 2499580    11-NOV-18
  1    56      2499580    11-NOV-18 2601155    11-NOV-18
  1    57      2601155    11-NOV-18 2601158    11-NOV-18
  1    58      2601158    11-NOV-18 2601263    11-NOV-18
  1    59      2601263    11-NOV-18 2601701    11-NOV-18
  1    60      2601701    11-NOV-18 2601705    11-NOV-18
  1    61      2601705    11-NOV-18 2601709    11-NOV-18
  1    62      2601709    11-NOV-18 2784642    12-NOV-18

BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
9       13.50K     DISK        00:00:00     12-NOV-18
        BP Key: 9   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20181112T195610
        Piece Name: /oracle_backup/DOMINO_O77/0bti2beq_1_1

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 9
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    65      2784741    12-NOV-18 2784798    12-NOV-18
  1    66      2784798    12-NOV-18 2784812    12-NOV-18
  1    67      2784812    12-NOV-18 2784830    12-NOV-18
recovery will be done up to SCN 2784849
Media recovery start SCN is 2397081
Recovery must be done beyond SCN 2397081 to clear datafile fuzziness
Finished restore at 12-NOV-18
```

The complete recovery is not possible, and RMAN reported the missing archivelog backups:

```
no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 63 and starting SCN of 2784642 found to restore
no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 64 and starting SCN of 2784723 found to restore
no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 68 and starting SCN of 2784830 found to restore
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll test it out and accept if works for me, thanks!

Comment: When I run this, my output doesn't look anything like that.  It does an implicity crosscheck, lists the Cataloged_files  and then fails with "RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 11/12/2018 14:31:34
RMAN-06085: must use SET NEWNAME command to restore datafile 1" .  Presumably because the name is different because its a test system.  DUPLICATE normally changes the name as part of its process.

Comment: @rfusca So try using `set newname`. In my database the `db_create_file_dest` parameter is set and that takes care of automatically naming files to be created, so I did not need it. If you are on at least version 11.2, you do not need to set each files seperately, you can use `set newname for database to '/whatever/path';` in the above run block.